# Best practices for counting very large and changing datasets

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, appengine-pipeline

This is not an app-engine question, per-se... though our application runs in Python on App-Engine using NDB against datastore.  So the question is about doing work on large datasets in a distributed system.

We have a growing dataset that we need to calculate statistics against (counts, sums, etc).  We have systems in place that successfully do this in a differential manner so that they are maintained transactionally as things change... but there are cases when we want to blow away our statistics and recalculate them from scratch... and or run validation routines to check the counts/sums we have been maintaining differentially

The question is, generally, what are some best practices for building statistics against very large dataset that is constantly changing in a distributed system?

Let's say we kicked off a large MapReduce job to sum a particular field on a million entities... and while that job was running several new entities came in, several were deleted, and several other summed properties changed.  What are some of the best known/accepted/successful approaches to making sure those additions/deletions/changes make it into the overall sum?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is that I don’t query all instances and run my operation over all of them every time. I have a separate entity group which handles these statistics in 1 attribute. Whenever I create/update an instance, I update the value of this attribute accordingly, and when I delete an instance I also update this value accordingly.

The best way to make sure that any updates do update the statistics entity group is to use [hooks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=en#hooks) that will run automatically every time you put or delete the instance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, we do this as well... but we have to get a solid baseline to start, which can be problematic if the dataset is very large.  Once we have the baseline established, we use hooks to track the differences

Comment: Could you elaborate a little, I’m not sure I’m following?

Comment: it sounded like you are keeping statistics on your entities in another set of models, and you update those stats as changes happen (example: every time a File is added/deleted you increment/decrement a counter somewhere).  This is fine, unless you have 5million Files and you need to count them all accurately so you can set your statistics.   Am I following you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to meet several conditions:

- track each individual MapReduce sub-job
- determine the individual MapReduce sub-jobs for which results would be affected by a transactional update
- ensure such affected MapReduce sub-jobs don't run simultaneously with the transactional update affecting them (might be ensured by the transaction itself?)
- determine in a transactional update, for each interfering MapReduce sub-job, if the sub-job has already completed

Then you could generate and apply differential stats updates for each interfering sub-job which has completed (maybe apply them after completion of the entire large MapReduce job?). The sub-jobs which didn't execute yet don't need such differential stats as the content will be already updated when the sub-job will execute on it.

You might need to treat the interferences for the additions, deletions and plain changes in a transactional update separately.

Alternatively you could store all MapReduce sub-jobs partial results, track which of them are affected by transactional updates (if any) and, at the end of the large Mapreduce job check if any update happened while the job was running. If so just re-run just the affected sub-jobs to get updated partial results for them and re-assemble the partial results into the final result. Repeat until no more updates happen while the most recent partial MapReduce re-run is in progress. More or less `rsync` style for copying/moving huge live partitions with minimal downtime.

You could even feed relevant impact info from the transactional updates to the mapper (a slightly smarter one), to leave the mapper itself evaluate the impact to the potentially affected maps and propagate the info accordingly to get the affected sub-jobs re-run, as the updates come in :)